# jquery/javascript to disable button within a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, struts

I have a table cell with 2 buttons in it.

```
<td align="left" >
 <input type="button" value="edit"/>
<input  type="button" value="save" disabled="disabled"/>
</td>
```

By default save button is disabled. On the click of edit button, save button button must be enabled. The problem is i cannot assign id's to buttons since the table is dynamically generated using struts2 s:iterator tag. If i do there will be 2 or more cells with the same id

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Of course you can create IDs, just supply a prefix. You don't *need* too, because you can use `closest` or similar to find the related button without having to refer to an explicit id.

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind [**click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event on `editButton` and use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set *disabled property* of `saveButton`. Its safe to put your code in [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so that DOM elements are ready before you use.

You can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wjW4E/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#editButton').click(function(){
          $('#saveButton').attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Above JavaScript should be processed post body load.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go by **ID**

```
$('#editButton').on('click', function(){
   $('#saveButton').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

If you have this kind of structure in multiple td's you can write a generalized event , where in it will only enable the button corresponding to the edit button..

For repeated structure with **no ID's**

```
$(':button[value="edit"]').on('click', function(){
       var $td = $(this).closest('td');
    $td.find($(':button[value="save"]')).prop('disabled', false);
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
      <td align="left">
         <input type="button" value="edit" />
         <input type="button" value="save" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left">
         <input type="button" value="edit" />
         <input type="button" value="save" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left">
         <input type="button" value="edit" />
         <input type="button" value="save" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
   </tr>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wjW4E/1/)**

Comment: but the problem is i cannot assign id's since the table is dynamically generated using struts2 s:iterator tag. If i do there will be 2 or more cells with the same id

Comment: You don't need id's in the first place.. Check the fiddle .. I have removed the id's from them..

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
$('#editButton').click(function(){$("#saveButton").attr('disabled',false)});
```

In javascript

```
document.getElementById('saveButton').setAttribute('disabled',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `id`s for each button. All you need is [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), single `id` for the whole table and `class`es for buttons.

1. Assign `id` to the table and `class`es to buttons, e.g. like

   ```
   <table id="dataTable" ...>
     ...
     <td style="text-align:left;">
       <input type="button" class="edit" value="edit" />
       <input type="button" class="save" value="save" disabled="disabled" />
     </td>
     ...
   </table>
   ```
2. Attach single event observer to the table (of course when page is loaded)

   ```
   $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", ".edit", function(event) {
     $(this).next(".save").prop("disabled", false);
   });
   ```

   It activates when user clicks on any button with `class="edit"` inside of table with `id="dataTable"`, then finds next button with `class="save"` after the clicked one, and enables found button.